# IAR embedded workbench, warning instead of error

Tags: iar, misra

When building I get for instance:
Error[Pe177]: variable "randomVariable" was declared but never referenced

I would like this to be a warning, not an error. How do I do this?

Using IAR embedded workbench for ARM 7.50.3

Thanks,
Mikael

Comment: Are you treating all warnings as errors? You should check the compiler diagnostics options.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecking 'Treat all warnings as errors' under Diagnostics did the trick.